# how to control 2 sensor and 3 relay with fuzzy

Tags: arduino-mega, millis, loop

i'm using fuzzy to decide how long the relay on pump on and i got some trouble for it he just looping on relay how should i do thats my code

```
    //---------Fuzzy 2.1 prelauch----------

//-----iNPUT SETPOINT-------
float inputec;
float inputph;

//----INPUT ERROR---------------
float ph;
float hasilec;

//----------fuzzy declare-------------
#include <Fuzzy.h>
Fuzzy *fuzzy = new Fuzzy();

//----fuzzy input Error pH-----
FuzzySet *LN        = new FuzzySet(-2, -2, -1.5, -1);
FuzzySet *FN        = new FuzzySet(-1.5, -1, -1, -0.5);
FuzzySet *SN        = new FuzzySet(-1, -0.5, -0.5, 0);
FuzzySet *ZERO01    = new FuzzySet(-0.5, 0, 0, 0.5);
FuzzySet *sp        = new FuzzySet(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
FuzzySet *FP        = new FuzzySet(0.5, 1, 1, 1.5);
FuzzySet *LP        = new FuzzySet(1, 1.5, 2, 2);

//----Fuzzy input error EC----
FuzzySet *N6       = new FuzzySet(-2, -2, -1.8, -1.6);
FuzzySet *N5       = new FuzzySet(-1.8, -1.6, -1.6, -1.4);
FuzzySet *N4       = new FuzzySet(-1.6, -1.3, -1.3, -1);
FuzzySet *N3       = new FuzzySet(-1.2, -1, -1, -0.8);
FuzzySet *N2       = new FuzzySet(-1, -0.7, -0.7, -0.4);
FuzzySet *N1       = new FuzzySet(-0.6, -0.4, -0.4, -0.2);
FuzzySet *ZERO02   = new FuzzySet(-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0);

//----Fuzzy Output phD-----
FuzzySet *ZERO1       = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0, 2);
FuzzySet *SEBENTAR1     = new FuzzySet(10, 20, 20, 30);
FuzzySet *SEDANG1       = new FuzzySet(20, 30, 40, 50);
FuzzySet *LAMA1         = new FuzzySet(40, 50, 60, 60);

//---Fuzzy Output phU------
FuzzySet *ZERO2        = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0, 2);
FuzzySet *SEBENTAR2    = new FuzzySet(5, 10, 10, 15);
FuzzySet *SEDANG2      = new FuzzySet(10, 15, 20, 25);
FuzzySet *LAMA2        = new FuzzySet(20, 25, 30, 30);

//---Fuzzy Output ABMIX------
FuzzySet *ZERO3         = new FuzzySet(0, 0, 0, 2);
FuzzySet *SEBENTAR3     = new FuzzySet(20, 40, 40, 60);
FuzzySet *SEDANG3       = new FuzzySet(40, 60, 80, 100);
FuzzySet *LAMA3         = new FuzzySet(80, 100, 120, 120);

//---------- EC declare---------------
#include <Wire.h>
#include "DFRobot_EC10.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>
int EC_PIN = A2;
float voltage, ecValue, temperature = 25;
DFRobot_EC10 ec;


//-----------PPM declare --------------
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "GravityTDS.h"
#define TdsSensorPin A1
GravityTDS gravityTds;
float temperatureppm = 25;
float tdsValue = 0;

//--------------pH declare---------------
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
float ph_H;
int pHSense = A0;
int samples = 5;
float adc_resolution = 1024.0;

//---------POMPA-----------
int pump1 = 5;
int pump2 = 6;
int pump3 = 7;
float pompa1;
float pompa2;
float pompa3;
unsigned long prev_pump1    = 0;
unsigned long prev_pump2    = 0;
unsigned long prev_pump3    = 0;
unsigned long initiate_start = 0;
int pump_state1 = false;
int pump_state2 = false;
int pump_state3 = false;

//-------Deklarasi Fungsi--------
#include "Fuzzy_Rules.h"
#include "Fuzzy_Set.h"
#include "PH.h"
#include "TDS.h"



void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //----FUZZY INITIATE-------
  sets();
  rules();

  //-----PH INITIATE---------
  
  //-----PPM INITIATE----------
  Serial.begin(115200);
  gravityTds.setPin(TdsSensorPin);
  gravityTds.setAref(5.0);  //reference voltage on ADC, default 5.0V on Arduino UNO
  gravityTds.setAdcRange(1024);  //1024 for 10bit ADC;4096 for 12bit ADC
  gravityTds.begin();  //initialization
  
  //-----Pin Output-----
  pinMode(pump1, OUTPUT);// Ph Up
  pinMode(pump2, OUTPUT);// Ph Down
  pinMode(pump3, OUTPUT);// AB-MIX

  //---normally open------
  digitalWrite(pump1, LOW); // Ph Up
  digitalWrite(pump2, LOW); // Ph Down
  digitalWrite(pump3, LOW); // AB-MIX
  
}


void loop()
{
  //-------------Fungsi Read sensor----------- 
  hasilppm();
  ph_s();

  ph = inputph-ph_H;
  hasilec = inputec - tdsValue;
  

  Serial.print("pH    ");
  Serial.print(ph);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("EC ");
  Serial.print(hasilec);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print(ph);  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(hasilec);   Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(" ");

  fuzzy->setInput(2, hasilec);
  fuzzy->setInput(1, ph);  
  fuzzy->fuzzify();

  float pompa1 = fuzzy->defuzzify(1);//pHDOWN
  float pompa2 = fuzzy->defuzzify(2);//pHUP
  float pompa3 = fuzzy->defuzzify(3);//ABMIX

  //-----------PUMP ALGORITHM--------------------
  long int pompa01 = pompa1*1000;
  long int pompa02 = pompa2*1000;
  long int pompa03 = pompa3*1000;

  unsigned long intiate_start = millis();

  //pompa1
  if(intiate_start-prev_pump1 > pompa01)
  {
    pump_state1 = !pump_state1;
    
    if(pump_state1)
    {
      digitalWrite(pump1, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(pump1, LOW);
    }
    prev_pump1 = initiate_start;
  }
  
    //pompa2
  if(intiate_start-prev_pump2 > pompa02)
  {
    pump_state2 = !pump_state2;
    
    if(pump_state2)
    {
      digitalWrite(pump2, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(pump2, LOW);
    }
    prev_pump2 = initiate_start;
  }

    //pompa3
  if(intiate_start-prev_pump3 > pompa03)
  {
    pump_state3 = !pump_state3;
    
    if(pump_state3)
    {
      digitalWrite(pump3, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(pump3, LOW);
    }
    prev_pump3 = initiate_start;
  }   

  Serial.println("Result= ");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print(" Pompa1 pHDOWN: ");
  Serial.println(pompa01);
  Serial.print(" pompa2 phUP  : ");
  Serial.println(pompa02);
  Serial.print(" pompa3 ABMIX : ");
  Serial.println(pompa03);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("");
  delay (2000);

}
```

im using NO on my relay thx for helping me

my library

1. https://www.codepile.net/pile/4Nvovokl [Fuzzy_Rules.h]
2. https://www.codepile.net/pile/96x8EO6y [Fuzzy_set.h]
3. https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_PH  [PH]
4. https://github.com/DFRobot/GravityTDS  [TDS]
5. Fuzzy.h its eFFl library

some library its a standar library for using censor

Comment: what is the problem? ... it is unclear what this means ... `just looping on relay` ..... also, what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Link to the library please.

Comment: @jsotola its just a looping on relay not on the censor and fuzzy for reading and calculating again

Comment: @EdgarBonet its to long i think

Comment: that is my logic 

Logic-->

Set pompa1,2,3 to zero

Get fuzzy values

Clean up - make zero if equal or under 0.67-->

Check if any pumps need to run-->

Convert the run time in milisecs-->

Get the present time in milisecs-->

add that to the runtime for each pump-->

Turn the pumps on that need to turn on-->


Find the longest run END time of all the pumps-->

Loop in while for the longest pump run time-->

Turn off pumps as they reach end time--->

but its not get the off just looping on pumps--->

Comment: Please, edit your question, and add a link to the particular library you are using. Do not worry about the URL being long.

Comment: okay no problem

Comment: Please, do not re-publish the code of the library. Instead, add a link to the existing official Web site. It has a Web site, right? Or did you author the library yourself and never published it? Or did you get it on a floppy from a friend?

Comment: like fuzzyrules and fuzzy set im minimalize using my library but the some library like TDS and ph from another site let me check it again

Comment: Its done maybe like that